# Is it considered good etiquette to leave a comment if downvoting?

Tags: discussion, comments, downvotes, etiquette

I was downvoted (twice) and there was not even a comment left as to why.
This happened on Server Fault, but I cannot post to their meta site, and it is equally applicable here on Stack Overflow.

Is it considered good etiquette to leave a comment if downvoting?

Comment: Apparently, someone down-voted this without leaving a comment.  Part of the point in asking is I think it should be required to say what is wrong with the post that it deserves a down-vote.  Otherwise one feels blind-sided by getting down-votes without discussion.

Comment: No, it should not be required. That's been suggested many times and is always declined.

Comment: Now I have four down-votes... and I can't delete the question because it has an answer.... what's going on?

Comment: On meta voting is different. It express disagreement (or lack of research in this case or both) and it doesn't hurt your rep so don't worry to much...

Comment: @JosephDoggie like rene said, I wouldn't worry about the downvotes, but my first guess is there are for lack of research because there are novels worth of dicussion on this very topic.  Commenting when downvoting is a very frequent request, although, I don't really see that actual request here, so I think the downvoters might be a little over-zealous.

Comment: It seems that no one cares that you should get a reason for a downvote. Oh the irony.. downvoted asking about downvote etiquette. BTW I haven't downvoted this question...(didn't upvote either)

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32973465/522444) is why you often shouldn't comment to down-votes. Folks just won't accept the down-vote, get all upset, and take it out on you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is. That is why every time you down-vote something, there is a blue pop-up box that encourages you to leave a comment so the other user can fix their mistakes next time.

Comment: Where do you see this box?

Comment: It pops up next to the down-vote button. It does this right after you down-voted a question or answer, unless you already commented on that.

Comment: I've never seen it. I downvoted your answer and it didn't show anything. I have not noticed it anywhere else either.

Comment: You don't see that pop-up at Meta SO (this one). You can see it at SO itself.

Comment: I do not see it there either. I haven't seen it ever and I've downvoted quite a lot. Please post an image.

Comment: Don't know how to do a screenshot correctly. Can't find mine

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I believe the message only appears for low rep users to encourage them to comment.  I think it stops appears after a period of time, enough rep, or enough downvotes.  I don't see this message either, but I have seen it on other sites where I have less rep.

Comment: @Sot The popup appears for under 2K users only.

Comment: Thank you. I don't remember it from then either. Maybe the feature came after I passed that threshold.

Answer (score 9):

It's always good etiquette to leave a comment asking for clarification of a question or explaining what's wrong with a post, whether you downvote or not. It's certainly not required, though, so it should not be expected. Voting is anonymous to avoid revenge downvoting (or collaborative upvoting). The downvote button already explains what downvotes are for (hover your mouse over it to see), so consider that the default reason if you receive a downvote without an explanation.